# Linux script in C get file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arguments

I have own script in C for linux, it is working with string loaded from file. I compiled on server `gcc -pthread -o pipeline pipeline.c`. It is working. Now I am running this script any like this `./pipeline UPPERCASE LOWERCASE < my_file.txt`. I can read all arguments but I dont know how to read file name behind `<` in this script. It is possible, or how is it working?

Comment: C is not a scripting language. Clarify what you mean by 'script'.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of that file will show up on your process's standard input (`stdin`). You don't get the name of the file, as the same interface will be used in situations where there's no filename, such as when the output of another process is piped to yours (`doSomething | pipeline UPPERCASE LOWERCASE`), or when the user's terminal is used for input by default.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you stdin is it what I looked for.